# How to make one loop animation in monogame(xna)?

Tags: c#, .net, animation, xna, monogame

Update method at Animation class:

```
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Timer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        if (Timer > FrameTime){
            CurrentFrame++;
            if (CurrentFrame == TotalFrames)
            {
                CurrentFrame = 0;
                Done = true;
            }
            Timer = 0;
        }
    }
```

How to adapt this code to make animation single loop?

Comment: Just add to the first if-statement if `Done` equalls to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `Done` to true, which is good, but you forgot to use that variable to check again.

So you should add a to your first if-statement if `Done` is false:

```
if (Timer > FrameTime && Done == false) {
```

Comment: It's breaks animation. I need case when previous key is down and current key is up (key press) to play animation one time, for moving i holding neccessary key and animation becomes looping.

Comment: Ah, you're using the same method for looping animations as well. That wouldn't work, you'll need to seperate single loop animations and looping animations in 2 methods. (Either that, or you need to pass a parameter that defines the differences between single loops and multiple)

Comment: So can you please give me piece of advice? Because i spent a lot of time and didn't found any useful information.

Comment: I found solution, dont need change Animation class update logic just need fix logic in Character class.

Comment: Glad to hear that it has worked out for you. You can mark this question as solved by checking the checkbox on the left side of my answer.